# php date not converting properly

Tags: php

I have this date in php: 31/01/2013

I'm trying to convert it using the strtotime function like so

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime(31/01/2013));
```

but it keeps displaying as 1970-01-01. Any know why this is?

Comment: `strtotime` expects a string - not a number.

Comment: 31 divided by 01 divided by 2013 equals 0.0153999006458023, which is cast to integer 0; which is the unix timestamp for 1st January 1970 at 00:00 GMT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work

```
$date = str_replace("/", "-", "31/01/2013");
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 5):

you should include it inside a string, not a continuous series of dividing numbers

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("31/01/2013"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$date = "31/01/2013";
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$date = "01/08/2013";

echo date('Y-m-d', $date);
```